# Spark SQL .withColumn() vs Column expressions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know if there is any performance/scalability difference when using **intermediate steps/columns** in pyspark between:

1. Using .withColumn() for example: 
   `df = df.withColumn('bar', df.foo + 1)` 
   `df = df.withColumn('baz', df.bar + 2)`

then calling `df.select('baz').collect()`

versus

2. Declaring a Spark column as a Python variable: 
   `bar = df.foo + 1` 
   `baz = bar + 2`

then calling
`df.select(baz.alias('baz')).collect()`

**Question:** If many intermediate steps/columns such as `bar` are required, would the two options differ in space/time complexity?

Comment: I saw my post was deleted. In hindsight It may well be that that was correct as the example I quoted had foldLeft. Barring the lack of communication by moderator. Your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw my original post was deleted. In hindsight it may well be that that was correct barring the lack of communication. That example was using a foldLeft which is not your use case which is fusing of the data pipeline.

To answer your question, the fusing of data pipeline operations by Catalyst means there is no performance issue either ways as the Physical Plans show:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(x,x) for x in range(7)], ['foo', 'bar',])
df = df.withColumn('bar', df.foo + 1) 
df = df.withColumn('baz', df.bar + 2)
df.select('baz').explain(extended=True)

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [(foo#276L + 3) AS baz#283L]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[foo#276L,bar#277L]
```

and likewise:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(x,x) for x in range(7)], ['foo', 'bar',])
bar = df.foo + 1 
baz = bar + 2
df.select(baz.alias('baz')).explain(extended=True)

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [(foo#288L + 3) AS baz#292L]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[foo#288L,bar#289L]
```

They look pretty similar to me ... Notice the optimize of +3.

In addition I draw your attention to using foldLeft with .withColumn https://manuzhang.github.io/2018/07/11/spark-catalyst-cost.html